# $X_i\sim\text{Exp}(1), S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i.$ $\mathbb{E}(\frac{e^{S_{n+1}}(n+1)!}{(1+S_{n+1})^{n+2}}|\mathcal{F_n})=\frac{e^{S_n}n!}{(1+S_n)^{n+1}}$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, martingales, filtrations

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{\mathbb E}}$
We need to show that $ \displaystyle \e \left( \frac{e^{S_{n+1}}(n+1)!}{(1+S_{n+1})^{n+2}} \mid \mathcal{F_n} \right) = \frac{e^{S_n}n!}{(1+S_n)^{n+1}}$.

The $X_i$'s are iid.

My only line of working  so far is:

\begin{align}
& \e \left( \frac{e^{S_{n+1}}(n+1)!}{(1+S_{n+1})^{n+2}} \mid \mathcal{F_n} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & e^{S_n}(n+1)!\e \left( \frac{e^{X_{n+1}}}{(1+S_n+X_{n+1})^{n+2}}\mid\mathcal{F_n} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & e^{S_n}(n+1)! \e \left(\frac{e^{X_{n+1}}}{(1+S_n+X_{n+1})^{n+2}}\right)
\end{align}

At this point I'm not sure on how we can proceed? Maybe by using the definition of expectation we could integrate to get the expectation (but this looks long-winded - perhaps there's a neater way)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly sure that the only thing to do here is integrate.  I expect that the integration isn't going to be as messy as it looks - I think you'll probably have a lot of cancellation.  Could you give it a shot and let me know if you get stuck anywhere?

Comment: The typographical difference between $(n+1)!\mathbb E$ and $(n+1)!\operatorname{\mathbb E}$ forces itself upon one's attention here. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname E}$
\begin{align}
& \e \left(\frac{e^{X_{n+1}}}{(1+S_n+X_{n+1})^{n+2}} \,\big|\, \mathcal F_n \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \frac{e^x}{(1+S_n + x)^{n+2}} \big( e^{-x}\,dx\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+S_n + x)^{n+2}} = \frac 1 {(n+1)(1+S_n)^{n+1}}.
\end{align}